# Fate of largest scale structures?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, cosmology, black-holes, structure-formation

In $\Lambda\mathrm{CDM}$, structures form "bottom up" with larger structures forming later. Structures are generally speaking supported by the velocity dispersion of their constituent objects (e.g. elliptical galaxies are supported by velocity dispersion of stars while galaxy clusters are supported by velocity dispersion of galaxies)$^1$. More massive virialized structures require higher velocity dispersions to support them. What happens when the velocity dispersion required to support a structure becomes relativistic and eventually exceeds $c$? Does the structure simply fail to collapse? Collapse to a black hole? Something else?

It occurs to me that the $\Lambda$-driven exponential expansion that is currently thought to be getting under way in our universe might be rapid enough to cut off structure collapse at some scale, avoiding the scenario I described above. For the purposes of this question, let's assume for convenience a model where the Universe continues to expand with $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\dot{a}(t)=0$.

$^1$ With the notable exception of systems where dissipation is important, allowing the formation of a rotationally supported disk.

Comment: Very interesting question. Can you point me at some literature on virialized LSS so that I can form an opinion? I'm not an astrophysicist by trade, but this sounds like a great thought experiment!

Comment: So, you're asking this for $\Lambda CDM$ minus the $\Lambda$ part? Also, have you heard of Jean's length or Jean's mass?

Comment: @JimdalftheGrey I have heard of Jeans length/mass, but I suspect that starts to break down when the dynamics of the system are approaching the relativistic limit. And I'm asking for... I guess LCDM without the L is a good description. Basically assume the Universe stays matter dominated for a long time instead of switching to $\Lambda$-dominated.

Comment: As $\dot a(t)$ approaches 0, the size of the observable universe grows asymptotically approaching $c$. Since there is an average density of matter and since the expanding edge of the observable universe will encompass more and more mass, at some point the Schwarzschild radius of the mass in the observable universe will be equal to or greater than the boundary of it. It's extremely difficult to say what will happen in this case because every point in the universe would essentially be the center of a black hole. Think about that scenario long enough and you go cross-eyed

Comment: @Jim I'm not sure I follow that... $\dot{a}$(t) approaching 0 means the universe is expanding arbitrarily slowly, not approaching $c$, no? And as expansion proceeds, the density is dropping, so I don't see any reason you'd end up with a global black hole scenario like you describe? Maybe I'm missing what you're saying, can you flesh that out into an answer?

Comment: The expansion is slowing, but the size of the observable universe is determined by how far light can reach. If the expansion slows, light can go farther, so the observable universe grows at a rate that approaches the speed of light. The density drops by more and more slowly. The Schwarzschild radius for a region of uniform density is proportional to the enclosed mass, which is proportional to the cube of the radius enclosing. The density of matter falls like $1/a^3$. Thus, the fall in density slows while the rise in mass accelerates. The scenario is unavoidable

Comment: I'd make this an answer but it doesn't answer the question. It answers a different yet related question. This answers "What is the fate of a flat, matter-dominated universe without dark energy?". You asked "What happens to structures whose required velocity dispersion goes above $c$?" Two different questions. I'm merely illustrating what happens eventually (and possibly before we have to worry about your problem)

Comment: I believe that Nikodem Poplawski, in a cosmological model using Einstein-Cartan Theory (which has been said, elsewhere, to reduce to GR in vacuum), mentioned (in what I think was a later one of his many 2010-2021 papers, whose preprints can be found by his name on Arxiv) that causal separation (of local universes, in a multiverse context) occurs when fermions spun outwards by larger-scaled fermions of a "parenting" LU) reach the speed of light:  I've looked for the exact reference many times, without luck, so it's probably in some bit of verbiage surrounded by ECT's unusual notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**They will form either separate universes or black holes.**

This is a really interesting (and old) question. Let me give a little more background before I explain my reasoning for the answer. As the question specifies, we consider a universe without dark energy.

#### Background

Collapsed, velocity dispersion-supported systems can grow continuously as they accrete new material. In general, they are $\Delta_\mathrm{vir}\sim 200$ times denser than the cosmological average (the "virial overdensity"). So a spherical system with radius $R$ has mass
$$
M
= \frac{4\pi}{3}\Delta_\mathrm{vir}\bar\rho R^3,
$$
where $\bar\rho=3H^2/(8\pi G)$ is the cosmological average matter density, $H$ is the Hubble rate, and $G$ is the gravitational constant. Such a system could in principle grow without limit. But the gravitational potential depth at the edge of the system is $|\Phi|\sim GM/R$, and the velocity dispersion of the system is $\sigma\sim\sqrt{GM/R}$. Thus, both special and general relativistic effects become important when
$$\frac{GM}{R} 
\equiv \frac{\Delta_\mathrm{vir}}{2} H^2 R^2
\sim c^2.
$$
This corresponds to $R\sim 0.1\, c/H$, that is, the system's radius is a tenth of the Hubble length. So we arrive at the question. *What happens when our system grows to this size?*

#### Separate universes and black holes

A similar idea has been considered in a more idealized context. If the density of the universe were to exceed the critical density, then it would have finite size and loop around on itself like a sphere. This universe would be said to be closed. But what if the density of *our* universe were exactly the critical density (as it appears to be), but inside our universe, *there is an overdense region of space whose size exceeds the size of the closed universe corresponding to that overdensity?* It would seem that this region of space should then be a separate universe, completely causally disconnected from our own universe.

The formation of such a separate universe was explored in detail by [Kopp, Hofmann, & Weller (2011)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.4369). There are some very neat diagrams in that paper, which I recommend at least glancing at. For example, here's an embedding diagram showing our universe (top) and the separate universe (bottom) shortly before the latter "pinches off".

[image: Separate universe formation]

However, the separate universe eventually collapses, since it exceeds the critical density. One of the conclusions of [Kopp, Hofmann, & Weller (2011)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.4369) is that due to this collapse, *the conformal structure of the separate universe-forming spacetime is identical to that of a black hole-forming spacetime.* The disconnected regions of space only arose because of the choice of time slicing (which was chosen to be synchronous, i.e., comoving observers on the same slice say the same amount of time has elapsed). In an alternative time slicing, they would not arise. So in some sense, forming a separate universe is not fundamentally different from forming a black hole.

This analysis suggests that our structure, which is $\sim 200$ times overdense and growing in size, should eventually become a separate universe, which is in some sense equivalent to becoming a black hole.

#### The velocity dispersion

But the separate universe analysis didn't consider a velocity dispersion. **Can a velocity dispersion support a *universe* against collapse**? If so, then perhaps a static separate universe could arise, which *would be* fundamentally different from a black hole. I do not know the answer to this, but I can give a few considerations.

On the one hand, cosmic structures grow from the inside out, with newly accreted material primarily remaining at large radii and not affecting the interior structure. As our object accretes material beyond the threshold to form a separate universe, the new material remains at large distances, *and there is no reason to expect that it should influence the interior at all*. In particular, it should not cause the interior to collapse.

But that's the Newtonian picture. Relativistic considerations might change it, whether special (e.g. the speed of light limit) or general (e.g. the briefly infinite blueshift of the continued accretion from the outside universe). Also, in black holes, there is a violent instability that arises in rotating or charged black holes from the interaction between infalling and outflowing material at the inner horizon ([Poisson & Israel 1989](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1989PhRvL..63.1663P/abstract)). I wonder if the velocity dispersion inside the separate universe might induce a similar effect.

In the end, I think it is fair to say that the structure will form a separate universe. Whether that universe promptly collapses (so we could just say we formed a black hole) or remains stable is unclear.

Answer (score -2):

This question cannot be answered objectively:

(1) Am I right that you are assuming a "static universe" with lambda to zero? That also means that you neglect Hubble constant (accelerated expansion) and ca. 73% dark energy of the LambdaCDM model. Your assumption contradicts reality.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda-CDM_model

(2) Cold Dark matter is responsible for structures in the Universe, but nobody knows so far what Dark matter really is. Can it move faster than light? Nobody knows.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lNNOaYwiu_U

(3) No spinning structures with velocity bigger than c has been observed. And in reality (without your assumption) our fate will be: our galaxy will merge with Andromeda galaxy and all other galaxies will be out of the event horizon. (So to observe your case becomes more and more unlikely).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity_dispersion
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SMSQu7C2gFA

Comment: A few objections: 1) I think he assumed a non-zero $\lambda$. 2) Is cold dark matter really responsible for large-scale structures? What do you have to support that?

Comment: @HDE226868 I think Randy's assumption (distribution of dark matter determines visible large scale structure) is based on dark matter being about 85% of the mass in the universe.

Comment: (1) $\Lambda \neq 0$ I specifically mention $\Lambda$CDM. I do indeed suggest assuming a cosmology that doesn't match observations at the end of the question, but this doesn't contradict anything else I've said. This can still be answered as a thought experiment (or the cutoff on structure formation from $\Lambda$ could be so large it won't affect the answer). (2) Can it move faster than light? I'd suggest that even though we don't know what DM is, we assume for the moment that it obeys the known laws of physics for a massive particle...

Comment: (3) I didn't talk about rotation anywhere, rather [velocity dispersion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity_dispersion)

Comment: @HDE226868, yes adipy is right, I refer (2) to the Millenium simulation which neglects visible matter./@Kyle yeah great question for scenario analysis, thought experiments. Make your own assumptions and start to do a simulation, e.g. in the Millenium simulation another assumption is to treat Dark Matter as a fluid, see this talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lNNOaYwiu_U and for the simulation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GzDlw8H6NpI